# Differentiability of Cobb-Douglas function of two variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, economics

I want to see whether the Cobb-Douglas function $f(x,y) = x^\alpha y^\beta$ is differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Both partial derivatives are zero $f^\prime_x(0,0) = f^\prime_y(0,0)= 0$. I need to check if the following limit is zero
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0) - f^\prime_x(0,0) x - f^\prime_y(0,0) y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0 $$
then the function is differentiable at the origin.

Replacing I get
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $$

If $g(x,y) = \frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ then
$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} g(t,0)= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{0}{t} = 0 $$
But
$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} g(t,t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} t^{\alpha+\beta-1} $$

And this last expression is not defined for $\alpha+\beta=1$, and is not equal to zero for $\alpha+\beta<1$

Is this okay? How about $\alpha+\beta>1$? Can someone help me prove that it is not differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $\lim_{t\to0} t^{\alpha + \beta - 1}$ does not exist if $\alpha + \beta < 1$ (the limit is $+\infty$). So $f$ is not differentiable if $\alpha + \beta < 1$.

You are not correct in the case that $\alpha+\beta = 1$. In this case $t^{\alpha + \beta - 1} = 1$, so the limit exists. But it's not equal to zero, which means $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Now if $\alpha + \beta > 1$, then $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} t^{\alpha + \beta - 1} = 0$. That isn't enough to say that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$, however.

If $\alpha + \beta > 1$, we can prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with the squeeze theorem. Note that for all real $x$ and $y$,
$$
    0 \leq |x| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad 0 \leq |y| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
This means that if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$,
$$\begin{aligned}
    0 &\leq \left| \frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right|
    = \frac{|x|^\alpha |y|^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
    \\&\leq \frac{(x^2+y^2)^{\alpha/2}(x^2+y^2)^{\beta/2}}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}
    \\&= (x^2+y^2)^{(\alpha + \beta -1)/2}
\end{aligned}$$
Since $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} (x^2+y^2)^{(\alpha + \beta -1)/2} = 0$, the term in between must also tend to zero.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Can you help me prove that it is not differentiable when $\alpha+\beta >1$?

Comment: @Pekisch I would use the fact that $0 < |x| < \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and the Squeeze Theorem

Comment: And $0< \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} < \frac{1}{|x|}$ but I would need to prove that $\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{|x|} \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Try to prove that $0 \leq |x^\alpha y^\beta| \leq (x^2+y^2)^{(\alpha + \beta)/2}$

Comment: I am not seeing the big picture.

What if since squaring is continuous then $\left(\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)^2 = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \left( \frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)^2 = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} x^{2(\alpha-1)} y^{2(\beta-1)} = 0 $ because $\alpha, \beta>1$. And since this limit is zero, the limit before squaring is zero too?

Comment: @Pekisch I've added more detail

Comment: Thanks. My solution is right too?

Comment: Sounds OK. I think you're using the fact that square root is continuous, though, not squaring.